# Implement power button function on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I was looking for a way to implement the functions of power button (lock, shutdown and restart) of windows phone 8/8.1 programatically. Is their any function for achieving the same?
I was searching online, but there were results only for windows os not for windows phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API to lock/shutdown/restart the Phone from your App.

Comment: But there's an application in windows store namely "Reboot now" which reboots the phone. Though it is not working on Windows phone 8.1 the reviews say it works on windows phone 8. How would he gave implemented it?

Comment: @user3263192 I can't say - maybe the developer has access to other API's or uses other methods. But for average developer AFAIK there is no possibility to do what you want.